# Why do we use 10,13 in message DB 10,13, 'foo $'?

Tags: assembly, newline, dos, x86-16, line-endings

Here is the Code written on assembly language for 8086 microprocessor.This code find if the number is positive or negative. I understand the code but can not understand the 4th and 5th line of that code.

```
       ;FIND A NUMBER THAT WAS POSITIVE OR NEGETIVE 
       DATA SEGMENT 
       X DW 28H
       MSG1 DB 10,13, 'NUMBER IS POSITIVE $'
       MSG2 DB 10,13, 'NUMBER IS NEGETIVE $' 
       DATA ENDS 

       CODE SEGMENT
       ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
       START: 
       MOV AX, DATA
       MOV DS, AX
       MOV AX, X 
       ROL AL, 01H
       JC NEGA
       LEA DX, MSG1
       JMP LAST

       NEGA:
        LEA DX, MSG2

        LAST:
            MOV AH, 09H
            INT 21H
            MOV AH,4CH
            INT 21H 


       CODE ENDS
   END START
```

Why they use 10,13 after MSG1 DB in the 4th and 5th line ?

Comment: In [ASCII](http://asciitable.com), `10` is line feed, `13` is carriage return.

Comment: Detailing @500-InternalServerError comment, those two bytes are requivalent to `\n` (for Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Internal Server Error's comment indicates `10` is the ASCII control code for line feed while `13` is the code for carriage return.  The line feed control code moves the cursor to the next line, while the carriage return code moves the cursor to the start of line. Together the two control codes move the cursor to the start of the next line.

Together these two control codes also form the standard MS-DOS line ending sequence, except in the other order. In other words, the sequence `13, 10` is the standard MS-DOS line ending. While having them in the incorrect order in your sample program is probably not going to make any practical difference you should use the correct order in your own programs. This will ensure that other programs that might read your program's output aren't confused.